# Memory leak! How can I fix it?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Ok, so I'm just learning about memory leaks. I ran [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) to find memory leaks. I get the following:

```
==6134== 24 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==6134==    at 0x4026351: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==6134==    by 0x8048B74: readInput(char&) (in calc)
```

So does that definitively mean the leak is in my readInput function? If so, how do I get rid of the memory leaks? Here's the offending function:

```
double* readInput(char& command){
    std::string in;
    std::getline(std::cin, in);

    if(!isNumber(in)){
        if(in.length()>1){
            command = 0;
        }
        else{
            command = in.c_str()[0];
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        return new double(atof(in.c_str()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
// ...
   return new double(atof(in.c_str()));
// ...
```

`new` acquires a resource from the free store which is being returned. The returned value must be deallocated using `delete` to avoid a memory leak.

---

If you are calling the function in a `while` loop, `number` should definitely be deallocated using `delete` before running the loop the next time. Just using `delete` once will only deallocate the very last source acquired.

```
// ....

while( condition1 )
{
     double *number = NULL ;
     number = readInput(command) ;

     if( condition2 )
     { .... }
     else
     { .... }

     delete number ;  // Should be done inside the loop itself.
                      // readInput either returns NULL or a valid memory location.
                      // delete can be called on a NULL pointer.
}
```

Comment: ok...got it. in my function main(), i declare "double* number = NULL". inside a while loop, i call "number = readInput(command);", followed by a if/else statement based on the value of 'number'. i don't think i can delete 'number'  after the if/else statement without bad results though, right? but not deleting it will cause a memory leak every time i loop through the while loop, correct? thanks!!

Comment: nope...just tried adding the "delete number;" statement in my main(). it did nothing to ruin the program or get rid of memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning a `new` double... When is that freed? You **do** call `delete` on it at some point... right?

Personally, I would recommend just returning non-zero for success and zero for failure and put the value in a `double *` (or `double &`) parameter. That way you don't need to bother with `new` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You return a newly allocated `double`.  Do you delete it somewhere?

Why are you returning a pointer to a newly allocated `double`?  Why not just return a `double`?  It isn't a big deal to return an eight-byte temporary value, and the caller can decide what it wants to do with it (including allocating a new `double` on the heap if it likes).  Assuming the values aren't large, I'd much rather return a temporary.  Having the `new` closer conceptually to the actual use makes the memory management easier.

Moreover, allocating large numbers of very small blocks can lead to inefficient heap use and heap fragmentation, so that the program might run out of memory when it wouldn't otherwise, and might not be able to allocate a large chunk even if it looks like there's plenty left.  This may or may not matter (and the extra time needed to allocate memory may or may not matter, especially in a function whose running time is probably dominated by I/O).  This is likely micro-optimization, but if there is no good reason for such small allocations you may as well get in the habit of not using them.